# Highcharts Deleting annotation throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts and trying to remove the currently selected annotation by calling `chart.removeAnnotation(chart.currentAnnotation)` which works fine but causes the application to throw

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at g.setControlPointsVisibility
```

here are the related parts of code :

options

```
chart:{
    events:{
        load : function(){
            var chart = this;
            document.querySelectorAll('.my-toolbar-classname .dbtn')[0]
                 .addEventListener('click',function(){
                     chart.removeAnnotation(chart.currentAnnotation)
                 })
        }
    }
},
navigation:{
    //other events are skipped here
    events: {
        showPopup: function(event){
            if (!this.annotationsPopupContainer) {
                this.annotationsPopupContainer=them.toolbarPopup.current;
            }
            if (event.formType === 'annotation-toolbar') {
                this.chart.currentAnnotation = event.annotation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the above configuration deletes the annotation correctly but as soon as i try to add another annotation to the chart error pops up.

Comment: Hi @saeed ghotb, Could you create some live example of the problem in some online code editor?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. Thanks for the reply. I looked more and found [this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7677) which seems like the exact situation that i'm stuck in. The example provided there might be enough. Don't know if some additional work should be done for performing annotation delete.

Comment: Which Highcharts version do you use? The issue that you provided is closed and fixed, so the problem should not occur in the current version.

Comment: @ppotaczek 7.1.1 also i probably should mention that i am working with react and using **highcharts-react-official** v2.1.3.

Comment: The react wrapper should not affect it. The demo from the github issue does not show the error in the latest version: http://jsfiddle.net/5L7ta5fb/ It would be very helpful to create some live example by you.

Comment: @ppotaczek I am really sorry for the late reply, weekend here!! So i solved the problem by looking into the error with a fresh eye and calling the **chart.navigationBindings.deselectAnnotation();** right before calling **chart.removeAnnotation(currentAnntin)** was the answer